# Incompatible block pointer types - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I want to call following code with return statement in main thread but I got below error.

> Incompatible block pointer types passing 'NSString *(^)(void)' to
>   parameter of type 'dispatch_block_t _Nonnull' (aka 'void (^)(void)')

Following is my code.

```
NSString *hash = [AGMobileService accessTokenHashForDate:date withParameters:[NSArray new]];


+ (NSString *)accessTokenHashForDate:(NSDate *)date withParameters:(NSArray *)params{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSString *accessToken = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).loginProfile.accessToken;

      NSString *paramsStr = [params componentsJoinedByString:@""];
      NSString *hashStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", [CommonUtil IMEI], [date agileHashFormattedString], (!paramsStr) ? @"" : paramsStr, accessToken];
      return [AGMobileService computeHash:hashStr usingHash:HASH_SALT];
    });
}

+ (NSString *)computeHash:(NSString *)text usingHash:(NSString*)hashSalt {

    NSString *textToEncode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", hashSalt, text];
    NSData *data = [textToEncode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if ( CC_SHA256([data bytes], (int) [data length], hash) ) {
        NSData *sha256 = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        return [sha256 base64EncodedString];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: and which exactly line is it? what is `computeHash`?

Comment: And most most importantly why are you returning asynchronously from synchronous function, how do you want it to work properly?

Comment: @Lu_ comuteHash is the class method which returns string. please check edited answer.

Comment: @Lu_ I got warning message like [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] must be in main thread. So, I am trying to call that part in main thread.

Comment: remove dispatching to make it work, you have to decide are you doing it synchronously or not

Comment: so the problem is somewhere else in the code, use dispatch in a place where you call `accessTokenHashForDate`

Comment: @Lu_Ok let me try it.

Comment: @Lu_ NSString *hash = [AGMobileService accessTokenHashForDate:date withParameters:[NSArray new]];

accessTokenHashForDate method call from above code but if I put it in main thread then how can I assign it with NSString* hash variable?

Comment: I don't know your app, but there is a lot of ways to make it clean, you should read about dispatching and async blocks to understand how your app works

Comment: @Lu_ I have edited my code.  please check it. I want to call accessTokenHashForDate:date method which returns NSString *hash. so how can I assign value to NSString using dispatch_get_main_queue().

Comment: put `NSString *hash = [AGMobileS...` in dispatch block instead

Comment: @Lu_I got your point but then How can I use NSString *hash outside dispatch block?

Comment: again, I don't know your code, you should not use it outside of dispatch block and in the end this warning: ` [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] must be in main thread. ` is completely unrelated to all of this code so why are you trying to change it?

Comment: If you want the computed hash value in `accessTokenHashForDate` then why are you invoking it asynchronously at all?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered things like this, I just remove the return code in the dispatch block, but I do not know the reason.So I also want to know the reason.

Comment: Not really.  The OP is calling a block that returns `NSString*` when the block is expected to return nothing (`void`).  While "remove the return code" might squash the error it doesn't help the OP with a working solution as the OP's code is clearly broken in its current form.

Comment: @trojanfoe  Yes, you are right, what I did could not fix the problem.  Thx for telling me about the reason. If  I want to retun the value asynchronously just like the poster want to do , what to do could solve this problem?

Comment: Generally you call a "completion handler" (another block) to deliver the result back to the caller in some way.